# Asus Laptop camera PID code

Tags: laptop, camera

I just installed windows 7 on my daughters laptop.  I want to make sure the on board web camera has the correct installed driver.  Asus asks for a pid code?  How do I find out what the pid code is?

Asus f3ka laptop

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

As ASUS seems to take some of their FAQs offline, here's the transcript in case the links go down again:

1. Enter into device manager.
2. Choose "USB 2.0... WebCam", and right click to go to "Properties".
3. Click "Detail", and find the PID number in "Value" as shown below.
   [image]
4. Go to the [downloads site](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx) and download the correct driver. The correct driver will be the one that lists the Hardware ID (PID Code) under "Camera".
5. Uninstall the previous camera driver before installing the newly downloaded one. Right click the device and click "Uninstall"
6. Then install the new driver

Comment: My  PID is C03E and I cannot find a single driver for that webcam (Asus EEEPC 900HA)

Comment: @TimothyP Operating System? I [found one](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Eee%20PC%20900HA/XP&p=20&s=1&os=17&hashedid=n/a) for Win XP and others, by your model number. Or don't they work?