# Where do I find a PID code for an Asus laptop?

Tags: windows-7

I just installed Windows 7 on my [Asus K52DR laptop](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=245&m=K52DR&os=&hashedid=eaAlHSngNQMAv1M1).

It asks for a PID code. How do I find out what the PID code is for my web camera?

Comment: There is a similar question here. Hope it helps http://superuser.com/questions/63952/asus-laptop-camera-pid-code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asus Laptop camera PID code](http://superuser.com/questions/63952/asus-laptop-camera-pid-code)