# Where to find drivers for built-in webcam

Tags: drivers, webcam, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS A550CA laptop and my HDD broke down some time ago. I got a new HDD and installed Windows from scratch. I also installed all drivers present on the ASUS support page for this model but there is no driver for the webcam. I searched the web but couldn't find anything.

In Device Manager I have only USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam with a Microsoft supplied driver. The hardware IDs are USB\VID_0BDA&PID_5606&REV_0530&MI_00 and USB\VID_0BDA&PID_5606&MI_00.

Where do I find a driver for this for Windows 8.1?

Comment: Have you checked Asus' website? This may help: http://superuser.com/questions/63952/asus-laptop-camera-pid-code

Comment: They don't appear to offer one on their site. Call/email them: http://www.service.asus.com/#!contact-us/cw8z, http://www.asus.com/ca-en/support/CallUs

Comment: What exactly to search for? If I search for 5606, I get nothing.